# Can UserJourney trigger an email to customer in B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I don't think it is possible but wanted to know. We have a use case where we wanted to send an email to the customer if a particular journey is triggered by a user. Just like a FYI email (say change of display name journey - we want to notify customer that you have triggered this and if not contact helpdesk)

Is this possible via XML and userjourney?

Comment: If you use custom policies (XML), you can add a REST technical profile. to test it easily: create a logic app (Http triggered) that send an email. Call the logic app from the technical profile and a a step referencing your technical profile.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks.. could you give some example? I am using custom policies. What would the REST technical profile and logic app look like and how to do it?

Comment: B2C documentation around REST: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw

Comment: Logic app documentation around email: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/tutorial-process-email-attachments-workflow

Comment: DId you get this to work? the custom policies don't like the ampersand characters in the querystring of the logic app. And from the docs i can't mix sending the claims both in body and querystring